# Howto set DEBUG & NDEBUG macros in Xcode Profiling and Archiving Builds?

Tags: xcode, configuration, build, profiling, archiving

In Xcode (currently version 4.3.2), I have the DEBUG and NDEBUG macro definitions set for Debug and Release Builds, so I can selectively include debugging code with the ObjC preprocessor.

Problem: When I select Product --> Build For --> Archiving, neither DEBUG nor NDEBUG are defined.  I have a similar problem with Product --> Build For --> Profiling.

Question: How do I properly set DEBUG and NDEBUG in xcode for the Archiving and Profiling builds, such that my conditional code inclusion (preprocessor) macros don't break?

My current workaround for Archiving a build before sending to the AppStore is to just temporarily delete the DEBUG code; but this is not a good practice, even though I'm protected by git's source-version-control-system.

Answer (score 5):

Try add your definitions into

```
"Preprocessor Macros Not Used in Precompiled Headers"
```

instead

```
"Preprocessor Macros"
```

Answer (score -2):

Check the build settings to make sure that the macro is defined in BOTH Debug and Release mode.

For example:  
- For Debug mode: NDEBUG=0 and DEBUG=1
- For Release mode: NDEBUG=1 and DEBUG=0

Comment: This is bad, because both would be defined always. If you "#define DEBUG=0", "#if DEBUG" would return FALSE, but "#ifdef DEBUG" would always return TRUE, because it IS defined, no matter what value it has.